# Simple System Call Implementation example?

Tags: operating-system, kernel, system

Interestingly, I couldn't find any simple example on web. Can you share a simple example please? I'm trying to understand following by analyzing an example.

```
⦁   Typically, 
⦁   a number associated with each system call
⦁   Number used as an index to a table: System Call table
⦁   Table keeps addresses of system calls (routines)
⦁   System call runs and returns
⦁   Caller does not know system call implementation
⦁   Just knows interface
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This depends on which architecture you want to add a system call for, or if you want to add the system call for all architectures. I will explain one way to add a system call for ARM.

1. Pick a name for your syscall. For example, `mysyscall`.
2. ***Choose a syscall number.*** In `arch/arm/include/asm/unistd.h`, take note of how each syscall has a specific number (`__NR__SYSCALL_BASE+<number>`) assigned to it. Choose an unused number for your syscall. Let us choose syscall number 223. Then add:

   `#define __NR_mysyscall    (__NR_SYSCALL_BASE+223`

   where the index 223 would be in that header file. This assigns the number 223 to your syscall on ARM architectures.
3. ***Modify architecture-specific syscall table***. In `linux/arch/arm/kernel/calls.S`, change the line that corresponds to syscall 223 to:

   `CALL(sys_mysyscall)`
4. ***Add your function prototype.*** Suppose you wanted to add a non-architecture-specific syscall. Edit the file: `include/linux/syscalls.h` and add your syscall's prototype:

   `asmlinkage long sys_mysyscall(struct dummy_struct *buf);`

   If you wanted to add it specifically for ARM, then do the following except in this file: `arch/arm/kernel/sys_arm.c`.
5. ***Implement your syscall somewhere.*** Create a file whereever you please. For example, in the `kernel/` directory. You need to at least have:

```c
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
...
SYSCALL_DEFINE1(mysyscall, struct dummy_struct __user *, buf)
{
    /* Implement your syscall */
}
```

Note the macro, `SYSCALL_DEFINE1`. The number at the end should correspond to how many input parameters your syscall has. In this case, our system call only has 1 parameter, so you use `SYSCALL_DEFINE1`. If it had two parameters, you would use `SYSCALL_DEFINE2`, etc.

Don't forget to add the object (.o) file to the Makefile in the directory where you put it.

5. ***Compile your new kernel and test.*** You haven't modified your C libraries, so you cannot invoke your syscall with `mysyscall()`. You need to use the `syscall()` function which takes a system call number as its first argument:

```c
struct dummy_struct *buf = calloc(1, sizeof(buf));   
int res = syscall(223, buf);
```

***Do note that this was for ARM. The process will be very similar for other architectures.***

**Edit**: Don't forget to add your syscall file to the Makefile in kernel/.

Comment: Hi, I've got a similar question in OS X, dealing with specific syscall that's already implemented in kernel. however, the implementation and calling seems different in input arguments. perhaps you can take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37656016/osx-setgid-system-call-which-api-is-the-correct-one