# OSX setgid system call - which API is the correct one

Tags: c, macos, bsd, mach

I'd like to use the system call setgid, to change the group ID of the current process. Trying to lookup this function, the only implementation I've found is in kern_prot.c :

```
/*
 * setgid
 *
 * Description: Set group ID system call
 *
 * Parameters:  uap->gid            gid to set
 ...
 ..
 .
 */

 int
 setgid(proc_t p, struct setgid_args *uap, __unused int32_t *retval)
 {
 ...
 ..
 .
 }
```

Notice that according to /usr/unistd.h, the API is completely different (`int setgid(gid_t);`).

1. does `int setgid(gid_t);` is a wrapper of `int setgid(proc_t p, struct setgid_args *uap, __unused int32_t *retval)`
2. Where can I find the implementation of `int setgid(gid_t);`?
3. Is there any option to call the implementation of setgid from kern_prot.c ?

UPDATE:

After monitoring my program with `dtruss` to observe system calls, it seems that calling `setgid(gid_t)` trigger the system call with 3 parameters 
`setgid(0x2, 0x7F9AA3803200, 0x1000)` which matches the implementation in kern_prot.c. The question is, where can i find the wrapper source code, and what library does it belongs to (maybe glibc? )

thanks ,

Comment: You are most likely correct in that the setgid API exposed to userspace is actually a glibc wrapper around the setgid syscall.

Comment: @mauzel, thanks for the comment. the only thing that still disturb me is that if i `#include <unistd.h> #include <sys/syscall.h> #include <errno.h>` and than run the following syscall than it seems to work and the api is with the single parameter (`syscall(SYS_setgid, gid);`). I still not get this contradiction.

Comment: so I know like nothing about mac OS X/BSD, but are you sure it's not calling this? http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sys.c?v=3.10#L646

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are you looking for is not opensourced. But if you open /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib in the IDA:

[image]

From xnu sources:

```
#define SYS_setgid         181
```

Here 181 = 0xB5

If you check `unix_syscall64` function inside bsd/dev/i386/systemcalls.c (from xnu kernel sources):

`code = regs->rax & SYSCALL_NUMBER_MASK;`

where `SYSCALL_NUMBER_MASK is ~0xFF000000 = 0xFFFFFF` (code is 32bit value):

```
#define SYSCALL_CLASS_SHIFT 24
#define SYSCALL_CLASS_MASK  (0xFF << SYSCALL_CLASS_SHIFT)
#define SYSCALL_NUMBER_MASK (~SYSCALL_CLASS_MASK)
```

so `0x20000B5 & 0xFF000000 = 0xB5` (SYS_setgid)